# Is it possible to find a word ending in every letter-vowel combination?

Tags: word, language

Take your five vowels and add each letter of the alphabet in front of them i.e. AA,BA,CA,DA.

This should give you 130 different letter combinations.

Is it possible to find an English word(not using proper names) that ends in every single one of the 130?

If not,what is the maximum number that can be found?

If it is possible,can it then be progressed to find two words for each?Three?Four?

Comment: This may take a while...

Comment: I don't understand the question.We have to find only "one" English word that ends in all 130 combinations??

Comment: Take a look at the tool here: https://www.wordgamehelper.com/words-ending-with/ac . Just replace the last letters in the URL with the ones you're looking for.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible.

I went and looked for words that end in what will most likely be the oddest combination, and there are no such words.

> The combination I looked up was "qu".  There is no English word that ends with that.

Comment: I imagine most Q-vowel combinations are impossible

Comment: I was not able to find words ending in qu, qe, qo, or xo.  I imagine words with double vowels may be difficult too (uu and ii).  I stopped looking after a while.  I think that the solution to how many there are available is best left up to someone with time to write a computer program. (I do not)

Comment: muumuu is a word ending in a -uu. I'm assuming we aren't allowing names, otherwise Hawaii would end in -ii.

Comment: *Periscii* has a proper entry in Meriam-Webster, being a term for the inhabitants of the polar regions (north and south of the polar circles). With -ii being a common plural ending in Greek, some lists of English words have plenty of entries ending with -ii, although most of them are not really commonly used.

Comment: Meriam-Webster also has an entry for *oxo* (adjective: containing oxygen). I am not able to find any words ending in -aa though.

Comment: _aa_ is a word meaning a certain type of lava, which appears in the OED. In addition, _radii_ is a common word ending in -ii.

Comment: @Carmeister Radii is the plural of radius. Not sure if that counts as its own word.

Comment: Well,I did it with a grid and filled them in as they came to mind-and got to 120.Some like JI,JO,KU or ZA looked fiendish,but turned out to be quite simple everyday words. C,F and V were rather difficult little pains...

Comment: @jarnbjo Perhaps [baa](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baa)

Comment: So far I've managed to do A completely. One way for this would be         baa,samba,alpaca,armada,tea,alfalfa,conga,mocha,aria,ninja,vodka,gala,gamma,iguana,boa,spa,burqa, tiara,visa,quota,aqua,lava,fatwa,coxa(medical name for the hip),papaya,pizza

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but only if you permit extremely rare words that are only used in very specific contexts.

The SOWPODS Scrabble dictionary has words ending with all but 4 of the combinations: **qe**, **qo**, **qu** and **vu**. Vu is used in the two-word noun *deja vu* (not permitted in Scrabble because of the space). Qo is used in *mesenqo*, an uncommon spelling of a traditional Ethiopian bowed lute. Qu is used in *shequ*, a type of modern Chinese community institution. And qe is used in *teqe*, a type of Albanian shrine also known by the Turkish word cemevi.

As for the second part of the question:

- The following combinations have just one SOWPODS entry: **qa** (*burqa*), **qi** (*qi*), **uu** (*muumuu*), **wu** (*mahewu*), **xu** (*xu*).
- The following have just two: **iu** (*piu, piupiu*), **wo** (*two, wo*), **yi** (*polynyi, lungyi*).
- The following have just three: **uo** (*duo, chechaquo, continuo*), **wi** (*iwi, tauiwi, kiwi*).